# Does a custom attribute on a custom tag need the data-* prefix?

Tags: html

I know that custom tags need to have a "-". And I kwnow that custom attributes need the "data-" prefix. But what about custom attribute on a custom tag?
If I define a custom HTML tag/element, such as `<x-sososlik></x-sososlik>`.
And I need some custom attributes on it. For example: hair-color.
Does that attribute need the data-* prefix?

`<x-sososlik hair-color="green"></x-sososlik>`

-or-

`<x-sososlik data-hair-color="green"></x-sosolik>`

The question is more about "what is the CORRECT way", because it works with both.
I'm asking because I cannot find that information.
I need to know it because I'm trying to shorten the attribute names on existing project, in the real code there a lot of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to use the `data-` prefix on an *autonomous custom element* (as opposed to a *customized built-in element*). As specified in [the WHATWG HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts):

> Any namespace-less attribute that is relevant to the element's functioning, as determined by the element's author, may be specified on an [autonomous custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#autonomous-custom-element), so long as the attribute name is XML-compatible and contains no ASCII upper alphas. The exception is the `is` attribute, which must not be specified on an autonomous custom element (and which will have no effect if it is).